# What comet server should I choose?

Tags: real-time, comet, ape

I need to incorporate some real-time features in a web app, mostly notifications and ability to chat between users. I found that [APE server](http://www.ape-project.org) fits my needs, they have impressive demos on their site etc. But soon after I started following their docs and tutorials it turned out that they're totally outdated and even the simple demo code on the main site doesn't work with the newest version :( Also it seems to be pretty much dead.

So, I'm looking for an active project with decent documentation. The only thing I really need is to be able to create a 'channel' where server could send (and receive) messages, preferably in json. Can you suggest anything?

Thanks for help!
jan

Comment: Check out cometD and atmosphere, there are some questions about them in SO

Answer (score 4):

We use the Comet server called WebSync from Frozen Mountain.  It is a .net based solution running in IIS.  It works pretty well, and we have been able to pump a fairly substantial load through it.